# Why is there a λ⁴ in the spectral overlap integral in FRET calculations

Tags: fluorescent-microscopy, spectroscopy, fret

The [Förster resonance energy transfer (FRET) spectral overlap integral looks like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B6rster_resonance_energy_transfer#Theoretical_basis):

$$
J=\int_{0}^{\infty}\bar{F}_{D}(λ)ε_{A}(λ)λ^4 dλ
$$
Where $λ$ is the wavelength, $\bar{F}_{D}(λ)$ is the normalized fluorescence emission spectrum of the donor(normalized to unity area), and $ε_{A}(λ)$ is the extinction coefficient ($M^{-1} \ cm^{-1}$).

I am not very familiar with resonance energy transfer but was just curious why would a $λ^4$ term be contained in this spectral overlap calculation. The intuitive implication would be that the longer the wavelength, the larger the spectral overlap?

---

See for example Eq. 12.1 on page 471 in [FRET and FLIM Techniques](https://books.google.com/books?id=uHvqu4hLhH8C&pg=PA1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=integral&f=false)
(Theodorus W. J. Gadella, ed. 2008) or the corresponding  $\omega^{-4}$ in the integrals of Eq. 14.30 of Sect. 14.5.1  in David L. Andrews' [Chapter 14: Resonance Energy Transfer: Theoretical Foundations and Developing Applications](https://spie.org/samples/PM194.pdf)

Comment: I don't know  why the ^4, but think about excitation energy with longer wavelengths...

Comment: If you write the integral in terms of dipole strengths the $\omega^{-4}$ disappears[[1]](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/journal-of-biomedical-optics/volume-17/issue-1/011003/F%C3%B6rsters-resonance-excitation-transfer-theory-not-just-a-formula/10.1117/1.JBO.17.1.011003.full?SSO=1). Perhaps, look at the relationship between emission spectra and dipole strength to see if that explains the $\omega^{-2}$ per factor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Why this is such a good question

---

After finishing teaching at 8pm EDT, it took me about 1 hour to find the answer and 1.5 hours writing this answer and confirming things. The Wikipedia article just [gives that formula out of nowhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLaky.png) and cites [[17](http://www.quantum-chemistry-history.com/Sina_Dat/BOOKIstaLec/IstaLec1.htm)] which is nothing but a table of contents (apparently not containing the string "rster" from Förster anywhere) for a book that I couldn't find online, [[18](https://books.google.ca/books?id=uHvqu4hLhH8C&pg=PA1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)] which is a Google Books ***preview*** of a book for which something ***related to*** the $\lambda^4$ does appear in Eq. 1.2 of pg 13 but explains nothing about where it came from apart from citations to {61}, which is missing from the Google Books preview, and 81-84 which are all books (unlikely to have a free PDF lying around), and [[19](https://spie.org/samples/PM194.pdf)] which gives the relevant formula in Eq. 14.1 but with no explanation and not even any citations to say where it came from.

Despite having worked in this field for a while, done my PhD in the general area, and even helped [supervise](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ct501066k) a student whose [Masters thesis gives a 5-page derivation of Foerster theory starting from page 30](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03277.pdf), I couldn't find where the $\lambda^4$ came from (the thesis presents the Foerster rate in a different way, which doesn't involve the $\lambda^4$, and I also looked at the reference in there to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0301010401005389?via%3Dihub) on my friend Suggy Jang's generalization of Foerster-Dexter theory but it was done in the same spirit as my student's derivation, which unfortunately doesn't help us today with finding the source of the $\lambda^4$).  I thought I was in luck, because my thorough studying of the field meant that I knew one of the best reviews on the topic ([this PDF](http://www.bmo.physik.uni-muenchen.de/%7Egilch/mol_dyn_08/reader/ann_physchem_54_2003_57.pdf) of a paper by Greg Scholes currently with 1238 citations on Google Scholar), but it turns out he literally just gives the integral on Pg. 62 with no explanation. The [textbook by May and Kühn](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9783527633791) might have the desired explanation, but I couldn't find a copy online. Every single paper and/or article I found online with a title like "Introduction to Foerster Theory" or simply "Foerster Resonance Energy Transfer" gave me nothing (some examples of the better resources I found were [this](https://www.azom.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=10458), [this](https://www.chemeurope.com/en/encyclopedia/Fluorescence_resonance_energy_transfer.html), some detailed discussions [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_should_donor_emission_spectrum_overlap_with_acceptor_absorption_band_for_fluorescence_resonance_energy_transfer_FRET), this **very interesting** article by [someone](https://www.pas.rochester.edu/people/faculty/knox_robert/index.html) who hung out with Foerster in real life entitled "[Förster's resonance excitation transfer theory: **not just a formula**](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/journal-of-biomedical-optics/volume-17/issue-1/011003/F%C3%B6rsters-resonance-excitation-transfer-theory-not-just-a-formula/10.1117/1.JBO.17.1.011003.full?SSO=1)" but then disappointingly it did indeed give "just a formula" at Eq. 4.

The [original 1948 paper by Foerster in German](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/andp.19484370105) (currently with 9994 citations on Google Scholar) doesn't seem to have anything resembling anything close to "the" desired equation. The [only research paper by Foerster](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/anie.196903331) mentioned in his [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodor_F%C3%B6rster) doesn't have the equation either, and the famous 1953 paper (currently with 9977 citations on Google Scholar) by Dexter that earned him a spot in the name "[Foerster-Dexter theory](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1699044)" doesn't have $\lambda^4$ or $1/\nu^4$ or $1/\omega^4$ anywhere, although now that I have the answer and double-checked all these articles to make sure I wasn't discrediting anyone, I do see that there's a $1/E^4$ in Eq. 16 but it's not as  close to your equation as what I'm about to show you.

## The answer

---

[This](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/4626886) 1965 "report" by Foerster actually tells us how he got the $1/\nu^4 = (\lambda /c)^4$ right here:

[image]

Basically after 53 pages which largely set the reader up for it, he gets this expression for the transfer rate:

[image]

In that equation, you can plug in the following:

[image]

which will mean you'll get a factor of $c/\nu = \lambda$ in the numerator coming from the molar decadic excitation coefficient $\varepsilon(\nu)$ and a factor of $(c/\nu)^3 = \lambda^3$ coming from the normalized fluorescence quantum spectrum $f(\nu)$: the two combine together to form $\lambda^4$. Since Foerster tells us that these are "Einstein's ***well-known*** expressions" for $\varepsilon(\nu)$ and $f(\nu)$, I assume you don't need help knowing why those are proportional to $\nu$ and $\nu^3$ respectively...

... just kidding, explanations and more references about the Einstein coefficients can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_coefficients) and [here](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electro-Optics/Direct_Energy_(Mitofsky)/07%3A_Lamps%2C_LEDs%2C_and_Lasers/7.01%3A_Absorption%2C_Spontaneous_Emission%2C_Stimulated_Emission) and you'll see expressions proportional to $\nu$ and others proportional to $\nu^3$ in both of those resources.

Comment: I even got out my QM text and skimmed through a few chapters... I didn't find it because physicists don't use those functions (the Einstein coefficients physicists are taught are these [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_coefficients]) Great detective work!

Comment: This is cool! Thank you so much for such clear answer!